# Express routing error Cannot Get /api/name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Having some trouble setting up the restful API for my express app.

Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'), 
methodOverride = require('method-override');
routes = require('./routes'),
api = require('./routes/api'),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Page Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:filename', routes.partials);

// // API Routes
app.get('/api/name', api.name);

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

In /routes/api.js I have the following test function:

```
exports.name = function (req, res) {
    res.json({
       name: 'Test'
    });
};
```

Currently I get the following error when i go to http://my_ip/api/name
Cannot GET /api/name

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: what you get if you `console.log(api.name)` app.js

Comment: @uzaif I get: [Function]. The function name() seems to be working fine. Something to do with the path to it

Comment: `api(app);` try this in app.js and check is it work or not?

Comment: Do any of your routes work?

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, i can navigate around the site so the /partials routes seem to be working

Comment: @uzaif when i try api(app) I get: Property 'api' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: its because of you have anonymous function in routes api

Comment: I'd suggest you try changing the property name `.name` in both places it is being used to something else in case it is conflicting with a built-in property on the exports object already.

Comment: You can also try putting a simple function right into `app.get('/api/name', put a function here);` so take the other module out of the equation and see if your route definition is working by itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 hm, i tried it with app.get('/api/name', put a function here); but still get same error. (With the function: function (req, res) {
    res.json({
       name: 'Test'
    });
})

Comment: I don't know.  I'd probably simplify my app a lot (comment things out) so I just had that one route and then get that to work and then slowly add things back.

Comment: I tried your code and it was working after omitting some lines of code. e.g. `routes = require('./routes'),` ,

Comment: @jfriend00 good call, i simplified it as much as possible and got the api calls working now. Now just need to put it back together and see where i went wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code is working for me. I think there is some issue with your routes package. Can you share the code of 'routes' package and file structure ?

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(),
routes = require('./routes');
api = require('./routes/api'),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Page Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);

// API Routes
app.get('/api/name', api.name);

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**/routes/api.js**

```
exports.name = function (req, res) {
   res.json({
     name: 'Test'
   });
};
```

**/routes.js**

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
   res.json({
     name: 'Index'
   });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I stripped down my app to just this and it works now. So I will work backwards and figure out where I went wrong in my main app.